# DOJO setting button active state doesn't work in if statement

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a function that gets called when buttons are pressed that takes in an enumeration as the parameter to determine what button was pressed.  I want to set the active property of the button that was set to true but it doesn't work when I do it inside my if statement.  The following works:

```
function buttonPressed(whichButton) {
            dijit.byId("myButton").set("active", true);

            // Other code here
        }
```

When I put the .set function inside an if statment, however, the button doesn't actually change state and looks the same when I press it.

This doesn't work:

```
function buttonPressed(whichButton) {

            if(whichButton == 2) 
                dijit.byId("myButton").set("active", true); //Button does not look visually different

            // Other code here
        }
```

I thought it might be an out of scope issue but I tried declaring and defining the widget outside of the if statement but that had no effect.

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is your actual code then your problem is probably here:

```
    if(whichButton = 2)
```

You're assigning here, in stead you should do:

```
    if(whichButton === 2)
```

And be sure that your passed parameter actually is a number of course.

Comment: Good catch but unfortunately no that's not my actual code.  I have just quickly retyped it but in my actual code I use the ==.

Comment: Okay, well was worth trying :). Can you set up a jsfiddle showing the problem? It is somewhat hard from this question to guess what is going on.